# Linear Programming, Optimal Solutions

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, numerical-optimization

[image]

I posted the whole question to give some context, but my problem lies with (iv). I think you're meant to use a formula for the generalization of the optimal solution, but I'm not really sure what this means or how to apply it. I have looked online but I cant seem to find anything that relates to this.

I know the two extreme optimal solutions are $\left(\frac{3}{7},\frac{24}{7},\frac{22}{7}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{12}{5},\frac{4}{5},\frac{46}{5}\right)$ and I understand that graphically $\left(1,\frac{8}{3}\right)$ will be on the line between them. I just do not understand the algebra on how to prove it.

Any help I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You know that $\big(\frac{3}{7}, \frac{24}{7}\big)$ is an optimal solution with a minimum of $24$ and if we substitute $x = 1$ and $y = \frac{8}{3}$ in $Z$, we also find a value of 24.
Therefore, $\big(1, \frac{8}{3}\big)$ is also an optimal solution.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is an appropriate way to show that $(1, 8/3)$ is also an optimal solution, which is what the OP requested.